# Function on half open interval is Riemann-integrable on closed interval

Tags: continuity, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I'm having the following question:

Let $f:(a.b] \to \mathbb{R} $ a continuous and bounded function on the open interval $(a, b]$.
Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on the closed interval $[a,b]$.

I tried to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $\delta > 0$ so that for every partition $p$ that satisfies $\lambda(p) < \delta \Rightarrow U(p,f) - L(p,f) <  \epsilon$, but I don't know how to estimate $U(p,f) - L(p,f)$.

Comment: A good example of this is $f(x) = \sin (1/x)$ on $(0,1]$.  It is extendable as a Riemann integrable function on $[0,1]$ -- even though it cannot be continuously extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function is Riemann integrable it must be bounded. This is a necessary condition and not just a part of the definition of the Riemann integral. Hence, to define the Riemann integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$, any  finite value for $f(a)$ can be assigned so that $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded. Ultimately the value of the integral will not depend upon this choice as the singleton $\{a\}$ has measure $0$.

Since $f$ is bounded on $(a,b]$ we have finite values $M = \sup_{x \in (a,b]}f(x)$ and $m = \inf_{x \in (a,b]} f(x)$.  Define $M' = \max(M,f(a))$ and $m' = \min (m,f(a))$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, take any point $x_1 \in (a,b)$ such that  $x_1-a < \epsilon/(2(M'-m'))$.  With $x_1$ fixed we have $f$ continuous on $[x_1,b]$ and, therefore, Riemann integrable. Given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P': x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_n = b$ such that $U(P',f) - L(P',f) < \epsilon/2$.

Extending to a partition $P: a = x_0 < x_1< x_2 < \ldots < x_n = b$ we have

$$U(P,f) - L(P,f) = ( \sup_{x \in [a,x_1]} f(x) - \inf_{x \in [a,x_1]} f(x)) \,(x_1-a) + U(P',f) - L(P',f) \\ \leqslant (M'-m')(x_1-a) +U(P',f) - L(P',f) < \epsilon$$

Therfore, $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ by the Riemann criterion.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @NaveTseva: You're welcome!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but what if $f(x) $ is constant  such that $f(x) = c $ and we define $f(a) =c$? We can't define x1 as the original defnition...

Comment: @NaveTseva: In that trivial case,we have for any partition $U(P,f) - L(P,f) = 0$ so the function is integrable and we don't need to define $x_1$ that way.

Comment: That's makes sense... thanks!

Comment: @RRL shouldn't there be an $x_1-a$ term, since we're technically adding that subinterval onto our partition $P'$? I'm a little confused here.

Comment: @mathstudentxdxd: Yes that is a typo.  The first term should be $(M'-m')(x_1-a)$ with $x_1$ sized accordingly so that the term is less than $\epsilon/2$.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @RRL Excellent! Does a similar proof of this property hold for functions that are not continuous everywhere? For instance, if $f$ is only continuous at $x=a$?

Comment: @mathstudentxdxd: If $f$ is only continuous at $a$ then it cannot be Riemann integrable  on $[a,b]$.  The set of discontinuity points of a Riemann integrable function must have measure $0$.  Perhaps you meant something else?